# Youtube keeps playing in locked screen on Fedora - is it a privacy concern?

Tags: video, security, fedora, privacy, lock-screen

While trying to search for this problem, I only got results like "how to prevent locking a screen while watching a video".

I have an opposite question. Playing a youtube video in Firefox on Fedora, I lock the screen (or put the computer to sleep). The video keeps playing in the locked screen (I can hear the sound from it). It feels like a privacy or security problem. If I locked the screen, I don't want anybody to see what I was playing, was I.

Is it a (known?) bug or is it by design? (Also, not sure if this is only in Fedora and / or only in Firefox.)

Comment: Locking the desktop in Windows never stopped any open applications from continuing to run by design. Logging out of the user account will terminate all running apps.